# Jquery Plugin to Generate Tree based on Level priority

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, treeview

I want to develop a tree based on Level priority. Please look at the below image. How to generate this with all lines(relations) using jquery.

[image]

Please suggest me any plugins which are nearest functioning to it.

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

use this [plug in](http://arborjs.org/). This is using html5 canvas and jquery